# SQL SELECT COUNT rawQuery with PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use the mysqli class from here: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

...and got problems with this rawquery:

```
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT id, value, (
                              SELECT COUNT( * ) 
                              FROM ".$dbprefix."pages
                              WHERE roles = ".$dbprefix."roles.id
                             )count
                             FROM '".$dbprefix."roles' ORDER by id ASC");
    $result = $db->rawQuery ($q);
```

It does not work, I get a fatal error preparing the query on line 776 in MysqliDb.php - the mysql query itself works, but when I use it with the mysqli class it does not work. I believe it's got to do with the COUNT (*) or striped tags or... something. I've tried several things but I stuck. Maybe I am not the only person with that problem- maybe someone can help out? This would be great! Thanks in advice!

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Are you shure that it works? ist should be "SELECT id, value, ( [...] ) AS count [....] " shouldn't it? And you should at least put count into backticks because it is a keyword.

Comment: First off, why are you using `mysql_query()` here? My guess is `$q` contains a value of `false` not your query represented as a string (try to `var_dump($q)` to see what you get. Second, why are you attempting a subselect in the SELECT statement? Have you considered a JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class, no need to mess with table prefixes manually - just set it with `$db->setPrefix(...)`.

Then don't do `mysql_query(...)` (which is deprecated anyway!) when your chosen library does this directly. `rawQuery()` is looking for a string with an SQL query, not the statement that `mysql_query()` returns.

Finally, avoid sub-queries and replace with various types of `JOIN` whenever possible - far better performance and far better readability. In general people way overuse sub-queries - get in the habit of trying to figure out a `JOIN` solution whenever you are tempted by sub-queries. Sometimes you have to use the sub-query, but most of the time not...

```
$db->setPrefix ($dbprefix);

$sql = "SELECT id, value, COUNT(pages.roles) AS c
        FROM roles
        LEFT JOIN pages ON pages.roles = roles.id
        ORDER by id ASC"
$result = $db->rawQuery($sql);
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future SO visitors) why you did what you did and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Better, @JayBlanchard? :-)

Comment: Much better @PeterBowers :-)